# C#/Unity - Unable to save scriptable object to disk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code of my scriptable object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ModelManager
{
    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Texture Set", menuName = "Model Manager/New Texture Set")]

    public class TextureSetSO :  ScriptableObject
    {
        [SerializeField]
        public RaceModelSO race;
        public List<Textures> textures;
        private RaceModelSO _race;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            _race = race;
        }

        private void OnValidate()
        {
            if (race != _race)
            {
                _race = race;
                textures.Clear();
                if (race)
                {
                    if (race.GetRaceBodySlots().Length != 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < race.GetRaceBodySlots().Length; i++)
                        {
                            Textures textures = new Textures();
                            textures.raceSlot = race.GetRaceBodySlots()[i];
                            this.textures.Add(textures);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Textures
    {
        public RaceSlotSO raceSlot;
        public Texture normalMap;
        public Texture albedoMap;
        public Texture metalicMap;
        public Texture ambientOcullsionMap;
        public Texture emissionMap;
    }
}
```

Whenever I use the editor to set anything inside the `List<Textures> textures` and then if I close Unity everything is getting lost.

Why is that? How can I keep the changes when close and open back Unity?
Any way to store that info to the disk ?

Comment: in case it helps, when I use scriptable objects, I do not do all the `OnEnable` , `OnDestroy`,  `OnDisable`, `OnValidate`...stuff I see in your script. Just inheriting from scriptable object, generation the instance from the menu option (`[CreateAssetMenu...`) and the dragging my fields to the `[Serializable]` classes exposed fields is enough. I suggest you might be overwritting your references in some of that logic in case its needed

Comment: @rustyBucketBay thanks for the comment. How is that related to the problem of not saving the scriptable object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The reason why this happens is that the

```
private RaceModelSO _race;
```

**is not serialized => Not saved.**

Thus, everytime you reopen the project `_race = null` and therefore the check

```
if (race != _race)
```

is true and you erase all textures.

---

**Solution**

If you need the other field `_race` to be serialized as well you will need to have [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) (btw it makes no sense on a public field)

```
[SerializeField] private RaceModelSO _race;
```

if you want to serialize it but not exposed in the Inspector you can use

```
[HideInInspector] private RaceModelSO _race;
```

you don't need `[SerializeField]` then, as it is already included in the [`[HideInInspector]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html).

---

**Note**

You should not call `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets()` here **at all**. You do this by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Makes little sense to do this in `OnDestroy` or `OnDisabled` at all for a `ScriptableObject` and is also extremely expensive doing it for every `OnValidate` call!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `EditorUtility.SetDirty(scriptableObject)`. Although you seem to call it inside **OnValidate**, OnValidate isn't called when modifying variables from code. It is called only when modifying the variable via Inspector or undoing/redoing a prior change.

An alternative to EditorUtility.SetDirty is to call `Undo.RecordObject(scriptableObject)` prior to modifying the ScriptableObject; this method also allows undoing/redoing the change.

P.S. You don't need to call *EditorUtility.SetDirty* or *AssetDatabase.SaveAssets* inside OnValidate. You also don't need [SerializeField] attribute on a public field.

Comment: `Whenever I use the editor to set anything` doesn't sound like runtime changes or via code is OPs situation. The issue rather lies in what is serialized and what not, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68579677/7111561) ;)

Comment: @derHugo You are right, I've misread the situation.